# panelAccordion inside panelTabbed does not expand

Tags: tabs, accordion, jsf-1.2, trinidad

I have a problem using accordionPanel inside one of tabs, I can't expand accordion item to show its content. Works nicely outside tabbedPanel. Can anybody help? I suppose it might be something with nested showDetailItems, but even when every component has its own Id it still does not work.

Here is the code I have problem with:

```
            <tr:panelTabbed id="pt1">
            <tr:showDetailItem text="Tab 1" id="sdiT1">
                <tr:panelHeader text="Header 1" />
                <tr:panelAccordion discloseNone="true" id="pa1">
                    <tr:showDetailItem text="Accordion 1" id="sdiA1">
                        <tr:panelHeader text="Header 1" />
                    </tr:showDetailItem>
                    <tr:showDetailItem text="Accordion 2" id="sdiA2">
                        <tr:panelHeader text="Header 2" />
                    </tr:showDetailItem>
                    <tr:showDetailItem text="Accordion 3" id="sdiA3">
                        <tr:panelHeader text="Header 3" />
                    </tr:showDetailItem>
                </tr:panelAccordion>
            </tr:showDetailItem>
            <tr:showDetailItem text="Tab 2" id="sdiT2">
                <tr:panelHeader text="Header 2" />
            </tr:showDetailItem>
            <tr:showDetailItem text="Tab 3" id="sdiT3">
                <tr:panelHeader text="Header 3" />
            </tr:showDetailItem>
            <tr:showDetailItem text="Tab 4" id="sdiT4">
                <tr:panelHeader text="Header 4" />
            </tr:showDetailItem>
            <tr:showDetailItem text="Tab 5" id="sdiT5">
                <tr:panelHeader text="Header 5" />
            </tr:showDetailItem>
        </tr:panelTabbed>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it can be something with maximum open tabs (showItemDetails) set default to 1. If it also applies to showItemDetails in panelAccordion, nothing can be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code and it works. Is the above code inside a

```
<tr:form>
```

tag?

I am on jsf1.2 and trinidad 1.2.14

Comment: Yes it was. After I have removed it from `<tr:form>` it worked! Thank you.